# Why do I see a Smiley instead of Next button?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, keyboard

My relatively newly acquired Samsung Galaxy GT-I9000 running Android 2.1 should have a next button around the bottom right of the keypad as per manual/online information. However, I can only see a Smiley button which doesn't have newline as one of the options.
Is there a user configurable option to switch between Smiley and Next? If yes, how to invoke?

Comment: Do you know which keyboard you're using? The Galaxy S comes with a number of different keyboards by default, you may be using a different one than the instruction assume that you're using: go into **Settings** -> **Locale and Text**, **Select Input Method** and see which is selected (you should have at least **Samsung Keyboard** and **Swype** as options).

Comment: As below - I use Swype. Samsung keyboard gives Next button. I should imagine next is a must whereas smiley is nice to have - regardless of input method (just an opinion)

Answer (score 4):

Can it be that you only have a next button when there is **more than one field** on screen ?

Please add what program you are using when you see this .

Comment: Agreed, using the Swype keyboard on my Galaxy S, the button on the bottom-right changes functions depending what app I'm in and what I'm doing, sometimes it's an Enter key, sometimes it's a Next field button, sometimes it's a Go button. I assume the same sort of thing happens on other keyboards.

Comment: Thirded, this is the same on my SGS Vibrant with the stock Android keyboard.

Comment: Hi. Thanks what I've noted since is that I don't have the issue on Samsung keyboard but Swype keyboard.

Comment: Also - to answer your question, I'm using it for regular SMS

Answer (score 3):

This is quite normal on the default keyboard. The smiley should only shows if you're typing in a single-line textbox (i.e. it have been configured so you cannot add newline), and there is only a single textbox in the page, and the app did not bind custom functionality to it.

> Is there a user configurable option to switch between Smiley and Next?

Not as far as I know. The developer of the app you're currently using gets to decide the "type" of keyboard that is shown by default, and they can customize the action button.

> If yes, how to invoke?

Try opening the browser, while on the browser, the smiley should turn into newline button (e.g. on multiline form input), or Go button (on the address bar), or sometimes Next button (on pages that have multiple single-line input).

Answer (score 0):

I have Jelly Bean 4.2.2 on a HTC One S and Swype 1.4 installed. I was ready to go on a shooting spree when I thought I couldn't hit a return button to start a new line!

I opened a SMS thread, tapped **Menu** > **Settings** and scrolled all the way down. There is an option at the bottom called **Soft keyboard type**. Open that and you get --

**<> Smiley key**

**<> Send**

**<> Enter for a new line**

Select the bottom one and you're golden!

This setting will change it for both the stock Android keyboard *and* Swype.

Cheers

Comment: Just to be clear for other visitors: this will change the behaviour for any keyboard, but **only** in the SMS app. As others have described, it's up to the app to choose whether an Enter key or some other action key is displayed.